# Why such low voting limit? Should it be higher?

Tags: support

At the moment I reached somehow my voting cap. Of course it is good to have some cap, but I'm feeling like it's a little low. Especially in the beginning of the site I'm very actively voting everything I think needs to be voted.

Maybe you can look to the rep of a user (total or gained that day) and relax or remove the limit in some cases? What is the limit at this moment?

Comment: You get 30 votes a day (see the FAQ).

Comment: @Shane Thanks! I overlooked that. Have you ever hit the limit?

Comment: Yes, I have.  I agree that it's irritating, although I suspect that there's good reason for it.  I listed to many of the SO podcasts, and I have no doubt that they have put good thought into that limit.

Comment: @Shane Yeah, probably they have. Although this limit is already two years old and maybe it should be reconsidered for SE sites?

Answer (score 5):

This limit is to make you consider what are you voting on; I have hit it once on SO. The random voting is to some extent desirable, because there are two badges that can be earned by casting 300 (silver Civic Duty) and 600 (golden Electorate) votes.

Comment: Yup, stupid error; thanks Jeff.